# how to implement google + , facebook login in rails with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, oauth-2.0, omniauth

I am a beginner to Ruby On Rails want to implement facebook and google+ login with devise gem.Application work fine loaclly but when deploy to heroku gives an error **Error: redirect_uri_mismatch**

Comment: YouTube tutorial on omniauth using devise    https://youtu.be/NUrrq6kI4vU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really ask for a more specific question regarding any code. This is too general!
Every gem that respect himself has decent documentation for it's use. 
usually github (it's repository) starts with a really good README file and from than start exploring the tool you're working with.
i.g: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Answer (score 1):

If you plan something strong from the beginning and have time to code and you want to learn. Then try to avoid device. Instead, use omniauth or omniauth-facebook

Otherwise this is a very good starting point. https://www.sitepoint.com/devise-authentication-in-depth/